# Echo out results using MySQL queries to query three tables in a table form

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking for help. I have 3 tables which I have to query results from. In the table model, I have `model_id` and `model`, in the table colour, I have `colour_id` and `colour` and in the table availability, I have `model_id` and `colour_id`. I have to echo out the results in a table format. The table has to show the model, colour and the availability. In the availability section, if the model is available in a certain colour, it must show/return a yes value and if not show a no. Here is ma current code:

```
$sql = "SELECT model, colour FROM model, colour";  
   $query = "SELECT * FROM availability";    

   $result = mysql_query($sql);

   $res =mysql_query($query);

 echo "<table border='1'><trbgcolor='#cccccc'><td>Model</td><td>Colour</td><td>Availability</td></tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $model=$row['model'];
      $colour=$row['colour'];

      echo "<tr><td>$model</td><td>$colour</td>";

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
      {
        $avail_id=$row['avail_id'];
        $model_id=$row['model_id'];
        $colour_id=$row['colour_id'];
      }


      if($res)
      {
        echo "<td>Yes</td>";
      }
      else
      {
        echo "<td>No</td></tr>";
      }
    } 

  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I don't see a question anywhere..

Comment: It seems like you could do all of this with a simple `JOIN` statement?

Comment: @DevlshOne I did try the JOIN statement and it gave me errors.

Comment: All this code displays the table but echos out yes even to the model  that is not available in a certain colour.

Comment: You should always try and let the query itself do all the work - it'll save you a lot of time writing code. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT m.model, c.colour, IF(c.colour_id IN (SELECT a.colour_id FROM availability a WHERE a.model_id = m.model_id), "YES", "NO") FROM model m, colour c ORDER BY m.model, c.colour
```

This should give you the results you want. Just format the output to your liking.